# Django: How to randomize choices field of every existing model

Tags: python, django

I have 100 instances of a Model, but now I've added a new choices Field with a default value. It is working and every instance share the same field, but I want it to be randomize between the X values of the choices.

This is a modified version of my model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
    C = 'c'

    CATEGORIES_CHOICES = (
        (A, 'Ant'),
        (B, 'Buffalo'),
        (C, 'Cat'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORIES_CHOICES, default=A)
```

With that I can go to the shell and type the following:

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
mymodel.category = random.choices(MyModel.CATEGORIES_CHOICES)[0][0]
mymodel.save()
```

And it works, but can I automatize it to do it in all 100 instances?

Comment: Write a for loop to loop over all `MyModel` instances?

Comment: Yeah, that worked but I didn't knew if that was the best option. Thanks ikkuh

Comment: You can also use bulk_update to limit the number of database hits, though if this is a 1 time operation, it probably won't have that large of an effect.

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: CoolestNerdll it's a one time operation but I'll keep in mind for the future

Comment: Willem Van Onsem PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a 1 time operation just make a for loop

If not try something like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

A = 'a'
B = 'b'
C = 'c'

CATEGORIES_CHOICES = (
    (A, 'Ant'),
    (B, 'Buffalo'),
    (C, 'Cat'),
)
category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORIES_CHOICES, default=None, blank=True, null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.category:
        # note sure for the syntax of this random choices
        self.category = random.choices(self.CATEGORIES_CHOICES)[0][0]
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

With this solution every time you save "MyModel" with None as category, a random category will be set before the save.

But this is not the best solution for data consistency